# declaring for-loop variable best practice

Tags: javascript, coding-style

My question is more a curiosity question on for-loop style.
While reading some old code by others, I encountered a style I haven't seen before.

```
var declaredEarlier = Array
for(var i=0, length=declaredEarlier.length; i < length; i++) {
    //stuff
}
```

I had never seen declaring a length before use and since this is an old app, was this kind of style a C/C++/old Java carryover? or was this developer unique?
Is there any benefit for declaring length that way instead of doing what I normally do:

```
for(var i=0; i < declaredEarlier.length; i++) {
    //stuff
}
```

If this has been asked before, I could not find it. And if it's not stackoverflow applicable, which forum would be better to ask?

Comment: In modern JavaScript, you should be using the [`forEach`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) method or a [`for...of` loop](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...of) instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two reasons you might grab the length up-front like that:

1. In case the length may change *(remember, JavaScript arrays [aren't really arrays](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2011/01/myth-of-arrays.html)* and their length is not fixed)* and you want to use the *original* length to limit the loop, or
2. To avoid repeatedly looking up the length on the object, since you know it's not going to change

The first is obviously substantive; the second is style and/or micro-optimisation.

---

* Disclosure: That's a link to a post on my anemic little blog.

Comment: Still relatively new to Javascript from a Java background. I never considered your first point. Do you mean that in the middle of my forloop, I or something else could change the array.length and I would have unintentionally increased my for-loop length?

Comment: Just tested my hypothetical. Looks like it does! I'm used to Java where array length is constant. Thanks for the insight!

Answer (score 1):

for the first style the value of `declaredEarlier`  can change so you need to use it
like that `length=declaredEarlier.length`

but for the second style you already know the value you dont need to calculate it again